# MySQL GROUP BY order

Tags: mysql, sql

Please consider the following table structure and data:

```
+--------------------+-------------+
|     venue_name     |  listed_by  |
+--------------------+-------------+
| My Venue Name      |      1      |
| Another Venue      |      2      |
| My Venue Name      |      5      |
+--------------------+-------------+
```

I am currently using MySQL's `GROUP BY` function to select only unique venue names. However, this only returns the first occurance of `My Venue Name`, but I would like to return it based on a condition (in this case where the `listed_by` field has a value > 2.

Essentially here's some pseudo-code of what I'd like to achieve:

```
Select all records
Group by name
if grouped, return the occurance with the higher value in listed_by
```

Is there an SQL statement that will allow this functionality?

Edit: I should have mentioned that there are other fields involved in the query, and the `listed_by` field needs to be used elsewhere in the query, too. Here is the original query that we're using:

```
SELECT  l1.field_value AS venue_name, 
    base.ID AS listing_id,
        base.user_ID AS user_id,
        IF(base.user_ID > 1, 'b', 'a') AS flag,
        COUNT(img.ID) AS img_num
        FROM ( listingsDBElements l1, listingsDB base )
        LEFT JOIN listingsImages img ON (base.ID = img.listing_id AND base.user_ID = img.user_id and img.active = 'yes')
        WHERE  l1.field_name = 'venue_name'
               AND l1.field_value LIKE '%name%'
               AND base.ID = l1.listing_id
               AND base.user_ID  = l1.user_id
               AND base.ID = l1.listing_id
               AND base.user_ID  = l1.user_id
               AND base.active = 'yes'
    GROUP BY  base.Title  ORDER BY  flag desc,img_num desc
```

Comment: I don't see `listed_by` in the 2nd query. And, do you mean "if grouped, return the grouped result with `SUM(listed_by)` > 2", or do you mean "return the individual row within each group where `listed_by > 2`"?

Comment: `listed_by` = `base.user_ID`. And I mean the latter option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you didn't mention other fields - here is the simplest solution:

```
  SELECT venue_name,
         MAX(listed_by)
    FROM tblname
   WHERE listed_by > 2
GROUP BY venue_name
```

With other fields it could look like (assuming there is no duplicates in `venue_name + listed_by` pairs):

```
    SELECT *
      FROM tblname t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT venue_name,
                   MAX(listed_by) max_listed_by
              FROM tblname
             WHERE listed_by > 2
          GROUP BY venue_name) t2 ON t1.venue_name = t2.venue_name
                                 AND t1.listed_by = t2.max_listed_by
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @zerkms. I have added the query that we're currently using to the question. I wonder if you might suggest how it can be modified to achieve the functionality?

Comment: @BenM: I don't see any valid query in the question. PS: why don't follow opposite - you take my query as a sample and add what you need in addition to it?

Comment: Sorry, have added it now (had some styling problems). My SQL is a little lacking when it comes to complex queries such as this, and I'm at a loss as to how I might proceed, otherwise I would happily work back from the example you have given.

Comment: @BenM: what if you take my query and add necessary logic step by step? "My SQL is a little lacking when it comes to complex queries" -- no it doesn't

Comment: Thank you, using your code as a base (and a fresh head this morning), I was able to make the solution work.